# Azure - use visual studio AzureRM module script to deploy web app failed

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project, everything seems ok. The Azure resources are deployed. But at the last step, when the package.zip is uploaded to the web app, it failed. However, the package.zip is uploaded to the blob successfully. Looks like package.zip cannot be downloaded.
Struggled and tried many times but failed. Anyone can help?

```
The entire error is as below:

16:26:10 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:26:10 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 
16:26:10 - 'webSiteqx6gdnwigzamg/MSDeploy' failed with message '{
16:26:10 -   "status": "failed",
16:26:10 -   "error": {
16:26:10 -     "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
16:26:10 -     "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
16:26:10 -     "details": [
16:26:10 -       {
16:26:10 -         "code": "Failed",
16:26:10 -         "message": "Failed to download package.\r\nARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'System.AggregateException: One or more 
16:26:10 - errors occurred. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace 
16:26:10 - ---\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from 
16:26:10 - previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from 
16:26:10 - previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of 
16:26:10 - stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()\r\n---&gt; 
16:26:10 - (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
16:26:10 - System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)&lt;---\r\n'"
16:26:10 -       }
16:26:10 -     ]
16:26:10 -   }
16:26:10 - }'
16:26:10 - At D:\source\project\luxu_source\energysolution\DeepMCDeploy\bin\Debug\staging\DeepMCDeploy\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.p
16:26:10 - s1:110 char:5
16:26:10 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
16:26:10 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:26:10 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
16:26:10 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
16:26:10 -    loymentCmdlet
16:26:10 -  
16:26:10 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:26:10 PM - Failed to download package.
16:26:10 - ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: 
16:26:10 - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
16:26:10 -    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
16:26:10 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
16:26:10 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
16:26:10 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
16:26:10 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__13.MoveNext()
16:26:10 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__11.MoveNext()
16:26:10 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()
16:26:10 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:10 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()
16:26:10 - ---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
16:26:10 -    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)&lt;---
16:26:10 - '
16:26:10 - At D:\source\project\luxu_source\energysolution\DeepMCDeploy\bin\Debug\staging\DeepMCDeploy\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.p
16:26:10 - s1:110 char:5
16:26:10 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
16:26:10 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:26:10 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
16:26:10 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
16:26:10 -    loymentCmdlet
16:26:10 -  
16:26:10 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:26:10 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment 
16:26:10 - operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage 
16:26:10 - details.
16:26:10 - At D:\source\project\luxu_source\energysolution\DeepMCDeploy\bin\Debug\staging\DeepMCDeploy\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.p
16:26:10 - s1:110 char:5
16:26:10 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
16:26:10 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:26:10 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
16:26:10 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
16:26:10 -    loymentCmdlet
16:26:10 -  
16:26:10 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:26:10 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment 
16:26:10 - operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage 
16:26:10 - details.
16:26:10 - At D:\source\project\luxu_source\energysolution\DeepMCDeploy\bin\Debug\staging\DeepMCDeploy\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.p
16:26:10 - s1:110 char:5
16:26:10 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
16:26:10 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
16:26:10 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
16:26:10 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
16:26:10 -    loymentCmdlet
16:26:10 -  
16:26:11 - 
16:26:11 - DeploymentName          : website-0421-0824
16:26:11 - CorrelationId           : 31181e33-d16c-48e6-8c14-3880ce240036
16:26:11 - ResourceGroupName       : energysolutionRG
16:26:11 - ProvisioningState       : Failed
16:26:11 - Timestamp               : 4/21/2021 8:26:09 AM
16:26:11 - Mode                    : Incremental
16:26:11 - TemplateLink            : 
16:26:11 - TemplateLinkString      : 
16:26:11 - DeploymentDebugLogLevel : 
16:26:11 - Parameters              : {[hostingPlanName, 
16:26:11 -                           Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable], [skuName, 
16:26:11 -                           Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable], 
16:26:11 -                           [skuCapacity, 
16:26:11 -                           Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable], [energyType, 
16:26:11 -                           Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable]...}
16:26:11 - ParametersString        : 
16:26:11 -                           Name             Type                       Value     
16:26:11 -                           ===============  =========================  ==========
16:26:11 -                           hostingPlanName  String                     DeepMCPlan
16:26:11 -                           skuName          String                     S1        
16:26:11 -                           skuCapacity      Int                        1         
16:26:11 -                           energyType       String                     Standard_LRS
16:26:11 -                           _artifactsLocation  String                     
16:26:11 -                           https://energyqx6gdnwigzamg.blob.core.windows.net/energysolutionrg-stageartifacts/
16:26:11 -                           _artifactsLocationSasToken  SecureString                         
16:26:11 -                           webApplication1PackageFolder  String                     WebApplication1
16:26:11 -                           webApplication1PackageFileName  String                     package.zip
16:26:11 -                           
16:26:11 - Outputs                 : 
16:26:11 - OutputsString           : 
16:26:11 - 
16:26:12 - 
16:26:12 - Template deployment returned the following errors:
16:26:12 - 4:26:10 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'webSiteqx6gdnwigzamg/MSDeploy' failed with message '{
16:26:12 -   "status": "failed",
16:26:12 -   "error": {
16:26:12 -     "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
16:26:12 -     "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
16:26:12 -     "details": [
16:26:12 -       {
16:26:12 -         "code": "Failed",
16:26:12 -         "message": "Failed to download package.\r\nARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()\r\n---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)&lt;---\r\n'"
16:26:12 -       }
16:26:12 -     ]
16:26:12 -   }
16:26:12 - }'
16:26:12 - 4:26:10 PM - Failed to download package.
16:26:12 - ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed: 'System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
16:26:12 -    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
16:26:12 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
16:26:12 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
16:26:12 -    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
16:26:12 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__13.MoveNext()
16:26:12 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__11.MoveNext()
16:26:12 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()
16:26:12 - --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
16:26:12 -    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__25.MoveNext()
16:26:12 - ---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
16:26:12 -    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)&lt;---
16:26:12 - '
16:26:12 - 4:26:10 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
16:26:12 - 4:26:10 PM - Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.
16:26:12 - 
16:26:12 - 
16:26:12 - Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.
16:26:12 - Tell us about your experience at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691202
```